# How do I use xUnit.net with Travis-CI?

Tags: nuget, travis-ci, xunit

I'm working on a solution in VS2013, which has two projects: a main project and a test project containing xUnit unit tests and NSubstitute for substitute mocking.

I recently figured out how to get Travis-CI to look at my GitHub repository and check if it compiles but I am having all kinds of trouble running my xUnit tests on Travis-CI.

How do I make Travis-CI run my (version > 2.0) xUnit.net nuget package installed tests?

Answer (score 2):

The answer was to downgrade to version 1.9.2 of xUnit.